# Hyphenation in python (apostrophe and exceptions)

Tags: python, hyphenation

I'm trying to get the syllables of word using [pyhyphen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyHyphen/). If I'm using the English dictionary, the apostrophe is handled correctly in my opinion

```
import hyphen
h = hyphen.Hyphenator('en_US')
h.syllables(u"Hammond's")
```

It's just included in one syllable

```
[u'Ham', u"mond's"]
```

But if I do the same using the German dictionary

```
h = hyphen.Hyphenator('de_CH')
h.syllables(u"Hammond's")
h.syllables(u"Bismarck'sche")
```

the apostrophe is seen as if it was it's own syllable:

```
[u'Ham', u'mond', u"'s"]
[u'Bis', u'marck', u"'", u'sche']
```

I was wondering how if it was possible to define exceptions (not to break) for certain characters? Like it is possible in [LaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165020/hyphenation-of-words-containing-apostrophes).

The workaround that came to my mind was just to look for a leading apostrophe in the syllables and just concatenate with the previous one:

```
syl = [u'Bis', u'marck', u"'", u'sche']
syls2 = []
for syl in syls:
    if syl.startswith("'"):
        if not syls2:
            syls2.append(syl)
        else:
            syls2[-1]+=syl
    else:
        syls2.append(syl)

[u'Bis', u"marck'", u'sche']
```

But this is not a nice or general solution and I'm interested in general, how to define hyphenation rules for words, where it is done incorrectly.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that those words shouldn't have apostrophes in German, right? They should just be `Hammonds` and `Bismarcksche`. If you are ok with just removing the apostrophe before hyphenation, how about `h.syllables(u"Bismarck'sche".replace("'", ""))`?

Comment: With Hammonds I agree, this is a bad example.

Comment: @leekaiinthesky Bismarck'sche is actually an taken from [duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/worttrennung#K168). A more frequent used example would be the omitted vowel of "es". "Seit gestern regnet's ununterbrochen".